# Why my iPhone app's downloads is high although I didn't publish anywhere?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I published an app but before I started to market it (no-one knows about it) I have 300 downloads in 2 months.
How come?

Comment: When you publish your application, your application automatically comes in New Release section of iTunes. Also, you can anytime block your application to be seen on iTunes and not to be downloaded. For that login to iTunesconnect.

Comment: @Dpk What can we tell ? The man published it and now he is wondering why is the download happening.

Comment: @PrajwalUdupa friend, I just asked to post your comment, I too know that this question is not a good one, but he will repeat the same mistakes if we did't let hm know where he had gone wrong! Thats why I told. Thanks

Comment: @user1999624 please read the FAQ to find out what's a good fit for a question on Stack Overflow to avoid downvotes and closure in the future.

Answer (score 3):

When you publish your application, your application automatically comes in **New Release** section of iTunes.

Also, you can anytime manage/block your application to be seen on iTunes and not to be downloaded. For that login to [iTunesconnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa)

Hope this info helps you..

Comment: @Oldskool Whats general info here. If its live on iTunesConnect, anyone can download it. I just stated him steps for not making users not to download app..